# Intron sequences in course of evolution

Tags: molecular-evolution

In course of evolution did some exons become intronic  sequences or will introns in some species acts as exons in other species.

Comment: There are alternative exons (and cassette exons). See [alternative splicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_splicing).